# What happens to chat rooms whose parent sites get closed?

Tags: discussion, chat, closed-sites

[Stack Exchange sites can get closed if the become inactive.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/04/when-a-site-grows-quiet/). The site contents are removed and are available only as data dumps.

However, [chat rooms have a more liberal retention policy](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention): they are kept permanently if they got at least 15 messages by 2 users.

So what happens to chat rooms associated with sites that get deleted? I think each chat room has to have a parent site, but these rooms' parent sites will cease to exist.

Comment: Here's an example: the [chat room for Astronomy.SE](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/516/astronomy) was deleted.

Comment: @AnnaLear: It only had 13 messages, though.

Comment: [The Firearms chat is still open](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1701/firearms). It isn't even frozen... I wonder if that's a bug.

Comment: Looking at the page HTML, it still considers that chat room to be associated with the now-dead domain: `host: 'firearms.stackexchange.com'`

Comment: @JeremyBanks: Also seen by clicking on the site rooms link. Add that as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's looks at some of these chat rooms .

#### Open

- [Literature](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1037/literature) - **1421** messages - re-parented to the new Literature site when it was re-launched
- [Economics](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1559/economics) - **36911** messages
- [Personal Manufacturing](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3669/personal-manufacturing) - **27** messages

#### Frozen

- [Atheism](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149/hub-of-reason) - 13651 messages (frozen by unknown cause)
- [Artificial Intelligence](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139/artificial-intelligence) - 75 messages (frozen manually)
- [How Things Work](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/427/how-things-work) - 518 message (frozen manually)

  - related: [How Stuff Gets Closed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/428/how-stuff-gets-closed) - 111 messages (frozen by unknown cause)
- [Game of Go](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1747/game-of-go) - **577** messages (frozen automatically)
- [Theoretical Physics](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1350/theoretical-physics) - **263** messages (frozen automatically)

#### Deleted

- [Astronomy](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/516/astronomy) - 6 messages (deleted by unknown cause)
- [Healthcare IT](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1570/triage-desk) - **14** messages (deleted automatically)
- [Sexuality](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2190/sexuality) - 548 message (deleted manually)

### Privatized

- [Firearms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1701/firearms) - **1439** messages (was made private; state unknown)

Rooms seem to have been deleted according to the normal rules, but for some reason many have remained open instead of being frozen.

Apparently the rooms are still associated with the domains of the closed sites; each page's source includes information about the room in JSON like this:

```js
{
     id: 1570,
     host: 'healthcareit.stackexchange.com',
     deleted: true,
     frozen: false
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Chat rooms are kept, as they are linked to the stack exchange chat, and not the general website. Great example being the firearms chat. This is still open, and it's parent site is listed as firearms.stackexchange.net. This however redirects to the dead Area51 Proposal.

They must still stay within the requirements listed in the original question to be kept however.