# Can the parent site of a chat room be changed?

Tags: support, chat, area-51

There is a [Pastafarianism Chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14251/pastafarianism) that was created as a child of English.SE.  As this is chat room for an Area51 proposal it the room should probably be a child of Area51.

I searched and found two somewhat related question [Unwanted feature: chat account auto-re-parenting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110188) & [What happens to chat rooms whose parent sites get closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163960/) neither seems to address this question.

The URL is not parent specific, so it would seem parent is an attribute that should be easy to change. Can a chat room have the parent site (also known as *host*) changed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the parent site can be changed.

The Pastafarianism chat room has been officially adopted by Area 51. :)

Comment: can the owner of the room  change it, or does it have to be an SO admin?

Comment: @user13267 On chat.so and chat.mse, it takes an employee with chat admin privileges. On chat.se, a moderator on the parent site should be able to make the change.