# Flagging a chatroom message as a means of getting a moderator to move the chat?

Tags: support, chat, chat-flags

I somehow created a [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41939/islamic-evangelism) on totally the wrong site. I read another meta post that said the best thing to do is flag one of the messages in the chat for moderator attention, so a moderator can move it. But when I tried to flag, I got a message saying use this feature only if there is a ***serious*** problem. I don't know if a misplaced chatroom is serious enough. Any thoughts?

Comment: Well, it *does* seem totally off-topic for ELU. If I were you, I'd just go ahead and mod-flag. But wait for others' opinion.

Answer (score 6):

That warning about *serious problems* is to prevent that the mod queue is filled with non-sense requests that can be handled with normal chat flags that are actionable by users with 10K rep or by Room Owners.

If there are no reasons to keep the nature of your request secret I would opt for a Meta post, either here or on the site meta you're an active participant on.

Changing the parent site of a chatroom can only be done by a moderator or an SE employee. Based on [this answer (and comment)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240609/can-the-parent-site-of-a-chat-room-be-changed) from [Adam Lear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/155160/adam-lear) this are the restrictions:

If the chatroom is on ....

- **chat.stackexchange.com**, any moderator ...
- **chat.meta.stackexchange.com**, only a Stack Exchange employee ...
- **chat.stackoverflow.com**, only a Stack Exchange employee ...

... can change the parent site of a chatroom.

So you now can link to this answer when you flag for a moderator or just wait for any moderator on an SE site to stumble on your question to take the honor.
 Stack Overflow moderators will have to ping an employee.

Comment: Well now I've really done it. Now I can't properly flag. There is no longer an option to flag my own messages as there was last night, so I crossed my fingers and flagged another user's message. But it didn't give me options like it did last night, like linking to this post. So now it looks like I flagged a post that says only "Yes?"

Comment: You suggested opting for a Meta post here. Does my question count as that post, or should I post another one that's more specific?

Comment: I would update your question with a final paragraph asking explicitly which chatroom you want to have the parent site changed. A dev or mod would cone along this and take action

Comment: The moderator flag is at the left of a message, the *normal* flag is at the right. Don't mix those ...

Comment: Ok, I see the problem now. On the messages I have posted in the last hour or so, the option to flag for a moderator is there. My confusion was that I was trying to flag a message that I had posted last night; the moderator option isn't available on those. Anyway, I flagged one of my messages and put an explanation there. Thanks so much!